# Cocoa App crash calling a 3rd party API

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

My Cocoa Objective-C app (in XCode) occasionally crashes in the part where it calls a 3rd party API. I believe that it's a memory leak or something. I attach the part where my program will, the 3rd party API and the crash log.

```
Please help to give me pointers on how I can solve this. Thanks a lot!

My code:

.
.
.
    uint8_t InfoProg[4];//10 
    uint8_t nInfoProg = 4;//10
    uint8_t ret;
    NSString *result;
    NSLog(@"***Calling GetConnectedProgramers***");
    ret = GetConnectedProgrammers(InfoProg, nInfoProg); // The part where it crashes sometimes
.
.
.


3rd party API function:

/**
 GET INFO ON CONNECTED USB PROGRAMMERS
 reports back the number of connected USB programmer devices on the host 

 @param InfoProg
        points to the memory that will be filled with the info on the connected
        USB programmers; 
        it is the responsibility of the application to allocate this memory 
        and to size it sufficiently. This should be an buffer with at least 8 bytes.
        InfoProg[x] = 0; no USB programmer allocated to that number
        InfoProg[x] = 1; USB programmer allocated to that number = USB programmer available
 @param nInfoProg 
        is the number of requested data structures 
 @return    
        is the number of programmers connected
*/
uint8_t GetConnectedProgrammers (uint8_t *InfoProg, uint8_t nInfoProg);

Crash Report:

Process:         FCT_MACOS [575]
Path:            /Virgo_FG2_EVT/FCT_MACOS3p55c.app/Contents/MacOS/FCT_MACOS
Identifier:      com.TopTest.FCTMACOS
Version:         3.55c (3.55c)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [132]

Date/Time:       2012-08-03 10:34:35.151 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D2001)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          16921 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           3
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  5164 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   3
Anonymous UUID:                      22314E10-99B9-4989-A2E8-53631295027B

Crashed Thread:  4

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000000005a5

VM Regions Near 0x5a5:
--> __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /Virgo_FG2_EVT/FCT_MACOS3p55c.app/Contents/MacOS/FCT_MACOS
    VM_ALLOCATE            0000000000001000-0000000000013000 [   72K] ---/--- SM=NUL  

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: isEqual:
objc[575]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x964edc22 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x964ed1f6 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9677ec7a __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 170
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x96787da4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1428
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9678747c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 332
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x96787328 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 120
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9973417f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 318
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9973b4e7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 381
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9973b356 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 88
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x957dfa9c _DPSNextEvent + 678
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x957df306 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 113
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x957db675 -[NSApplication run] + 911
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x95a6f261 NSApplicationMain + 1054
13  com.TopTest.FCTMACOS            0x00014055 start + 53

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x964f090a kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x97c1dc58 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 969
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x97c1c6a7 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 53

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x964f0ef2 __sem_wait + 10
1   com.ni.framework.nipalu         0x001ebd0b tTimerTimeWasterSleep::sleep(u64, tTimerTimeUnit, long*) const + 3019
2   com.ni.framework.NI4882         0x06cad33c WaitSRQ + 99996
3   com.ni.framework.nipalu         0x001edc78 tThreadUtility::getCurrentThreadId() + 104
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918aeed9 _pthread_start + 335
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b26de thread_start + 34

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x964edc22 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x964ed1f6 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x982f92df io_connect_method + 465
3   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x982a9f21 IOConnectCallMethod + 559
4   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x982aa21b IOConnectCallStructMethod + 84
5   com.ni.framework.nipalu         0x001f11f1 tThreadUtility::yield(iThreadController*, long*) + 12993
6   com.ni.framework.nipalu         0x001ec4b3 tTimerTimeWasterSleep::sleep(u64, tTimerTimeUnit, long*) const + 4979
7   com.ni.framework.NI4882         0x06c9940a WaitSRQ + 18282
8   com.ni.framework.nipalu         0x001edc78 tThreadUtility::getCurrentThreadId() + 104
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918aeed9 _pthread_start + 335
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b26de thread_start + 34

Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x915bcd47 objc_msgSend + 23
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9675b57a CFEqual + 154
2   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x982cbc80 IOHIDDeviceUnscheduleFromRunLoop + 29
3   com.TopTest.FCTMACOS            0x0008dee2 closeAll + 66
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x967ea298 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 72
5   com.TopTest.FCTMACOS            0x000213ff -[TestViewController threadRunTest:] + 2593
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x97ddbe59 -[NSThread main] + 45
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x97ddbe09 __NSThread__main__ + 1582
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918aeed9 _pthread_start + 335
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b26de thread_start + 34

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x964f002e __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b0ccf _pthread_wqthread + 773
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b26fe start_wqthread + 30

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x964f002e __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b0ccf _pthread_wqthread + 773
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b26fe start_wqthread + 30

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x964f002e __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b0ccf _pthread_wqthread + 773
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b26fe start_wqthread + 30

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x964f002e __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b0ccf _pthread_wqthread + 773
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b26fe start_wqthread + 30

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x964f002e __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b0ccf _pthread_wqthread + 773
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b26fe start_wqthread + 30

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x964efbb2 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918637b9 nanosleep$UNIX2003 + 187
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x97e1c05f +[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:] + 170
3   com.TopTest.FCTMACOS            0x0006cbd7 -[RS232 threadB139RS232Read:] + 223
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x97ddbe59 -[NSThread main] + 45
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x97ddbe09 __NSThread__main__ + 1582
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918aeed9 _pthread_start + 335
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x918b26de thread_start + 34

Thread 4 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x78690d00  ebx: 0xac7d8724  ecx: 0x96128a48  edx: 0x00000585
  edi: 0x7868cc80  esi: 0x78615800  ebp: 0xb0102c18  esp: 0xb0102bf8
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010206  eip: 0x915bcd47   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x000005a5
Logical CPU: 2
```

...

Answer (score 2):

From the docs;

```
@param InfoProg
 This should be an buffer with at least 8 bytes.
```

but

```
uint8_t InfoProg[4];
```

only consists of 4 uint8_t (bytes). Try increasing your buffer.

Comment: +1 I would raise a defect with the third party API designers since it would be so easy to validate the size of the buffer and return some sort of error instead of just crashing.